# Problem installing cryptography on MacOS Monterey with ARM chip

Tags: python-3.x, openssl

I am trying to install the cryptography package on my MacBook with ARM chip running Monterey MacOS. The command I issue is

```
pip3 install cryptography --global-option=build_ext 
  --global-option="-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1m/lib/"
  --global-option="-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1m/include"
```

I am getting the error:

```
build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/_openssl.c:575:10: 
   fatal error: '***openssl/opensslv.h***' file not found
```

`#include <openssl/opensslv.h>`. I definitely have that file under `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1m/include/`, and that directory is in my path. Please, advise what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.

Try installing openssl with brew

> brew install openssl

, then what really does the trick is in cryptography's documentation: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/

> brew install openssl@1.1 rust

> env LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/include" pip3 install cryptography

Don't forget to adjust pip/pip3 and cryptography's versions as needed at the end of the command.

Hope it works for you as well! :)

Comment: Did this work for you? I hope it did!